# Passing variable into a dialog box

Tags: jquery, variables, dialog

I'm making a messaging system for a webpage im creating. I'm wanting to click on a button next to someones name and have their name appear in the dialog box to know im sending it to them.

This is the DIV i'm trying to make it appear in. The modal is working correctly buy no matter which person i click, it's bringing back the same name into the "to" field.

```
<div id='chatPop' style="display: none;">
      Messages
      <hr>
      To: <?Php echo $userId ?>
      <br><br><br>
      From:
      <br><br><br>
      Message:-<textarea> </textarea>
</div>
```

Here's my JS which is opening the dialog already:

```
function doPop(userId)
{
$("#chatPop")

.dialog({
      float: top,
      resizable: true,
      height: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Send: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
      }
```

And this is my PHP which is inside of a div and is working but not passing the $userId how i would like:

```
              <?php
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<a>";
                $userId = $row ['userId'];
                echo $userId;
                echo " <input type=button value=chat onclick=doPop('$userId')>";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</li>";
              }
              mysqli_close($con1);
              ?>
```

Comment: Are you showing to and from as just static text, not inputs?  If this is going to be submitted via a form then you'll need to have the values in inputs.  Also, you can't run PHP code in your browser - it runs on the server.  The value next to `To:` will be set before the browser ever gets the page, and won't be changed by passing a new value into the JS function.

Comment: @archer If there is a user called 'Bob' i'm wanting it to show 'To: Bob' once you click on his name in the table. The modal is showing but its just putting the wrong name into the window if that helps

Comment: I understand that you want to click a user and get their name in the dialog.  Sorry, but that doesn't change anything that I previously said.  Please answer the questions I asked or it will be difficult to help you without guessing 1/2 your code for you.

Comment: Yes at the moment they are, i'm planning for it to be submitted by form so  i'll need to change them into inputs.

Comment: Thanks - that helps.  There's a couple of answers below now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your dialog markup to this

```
<div id='chatPop' style="display: none;">
      Messages
      <hr>
      To: <input type="text" name="to" id="send-to" />
      <br><br><br>
      From: <input type="text" name="from" id="sent-from" />
      <br><br><br>
      Message:-<textarea name="message" id="message"> </textarea>
</div>
```

and change your dialog function to this...

```
function doPop(userId) {
    $("#send-to").val(userId);
    $("#chatPop")
        .dialog({
            float: top,
            resizable: true,
            height: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Send: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

**HTML**

```
<div id='chatPop' style="display: none;">
      Messages
      <hr>
      To: <span id="userid"></span>
      <br><br><br>
      From:
      <br><br><br>
      Message:-<textarea> </textarea>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function doPop(userId)
{
   $("#userid").html(userId);

   $("#chatPop").dialog({
      float: top,
      resizable: true,
      height: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Send: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dialog markup to this...

```
<div id='chatPop' style="display: none;">
      Messages
      <hr>
      To: <input type="text" name="to" id="send-to" />
      <br><br><br>
      From: <input type="text" name="from" id="sent-from" />
      <br><br><br>
      Message:-<textarea name="message" id="message"> </textarea>
</div>
```

and change your dialog function to this...

```
function doPop(userId) {
    $("#send-to").val(userId);
    $("#chatPop")
        .dialog({
            float: top,
            resizable: true,
            height: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Send: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The name properties of the inputs are for when you have wrapped it in a form that you wish to submit (assuming you'll use the `Send` button callback for that).  The IDs are so that you can refer to things using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dialog markup to this

```
<div id='chatPop' style="display: none;">
      Messages
      <hr>
      To: <input type="text" name="to" id="send-to" />
      <br><br><br>
      From: <input type="text" name="from" id="sent-from" />
      <br><br><br>
      Message:-<textarea name="message" id="message"> </textarea>
</div>
```

and change your dialog function to this...

```
function doPop(userId) {
    $("#send-to").val(userId);
    $("#chatPop")
        .dialog({
            float: top,
            resizable: true,
            height: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Send: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });
```

}